# Show $(\mathcal S\times\mathcal S,*)$ with $|\mathcal S|\ge 2$ & $(a,b)*(c,d) = (c,b)$ is a semigroup without a one & $(a,b)^2=(a,b)\forall(a,b)$

Tags: semigroups, idempotents

> Let $\mathcal S$ be a set with at least two elements. Consider the operation $\ast$ defined on $\mathcal S $$\times$$\mathcal S$ by
>
> $$(a,b) \ast(c,d) = (c,b).$$
>
> How can I show that $(\mathcal S\times\mathcal S,\ast)$ is a semigroup without identity in which all elements are idempotent?

(I'm preping for an exam, it's not either for homework neither I'm in the middle of an exam)

Thanks

Comment: Just expanding the definitions: you can check that (1) $*$ is associative [so $(S\times S,*)$ is a semigroup], (2) For any $(a,b)\in S\times S$, there is some $(c,d)\in S\times S$ such that $(a,b)*(c,d)\neq (c,d)$ [so there is no identity], and (3) $(a,b)*(a,b) = (a,b)$ for all $(a,b)\in S\times S$ [so all elements are idempotent].

Comment: Of course, you probably know these definitions (if not, you should first make sure you understand all the words in the question before posting!). So you must have been stuck on (1), (2), and/or (3). What did you try, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I got stuck on (1), how can I just by looking at the expression bring down the associativism?

Comment: I've written out the check for associativity in an answer below. Tip: Your questions will be better received if you show some effort by explaining your thoughts on the problem and what problems you're having, rather than just posting a problem verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

Just expanding the definitions: you can check that (1) $*$ is associative [so $(S\times S,*)$ is a semigroup], (2) For any $(a,b)\in S\times S$, there is some $(c,d)\in S\times S$ such that $(a,b)*(c,d)\neq (c,d)$ [so there is no identity], and (3) $(a,b)*(a,b) = (a,b)$ for all $(a,b\in S\times S$ [so all elements are idempotent].

In the comments, you say you got stuck on (1). Let's check: 
$$
((a,b)*(c,d))*(e,f) = (c,b)*(e,f) = (e,b)
$$
and
$$
(a,b)*((c,d)*(e,f)) = (a,b)*(e,d) = (e,b)
$$
so the operation is associative.

Answer (score 1):

What’s $(a,b)^2=(a,b)(a,b)$?

What’s the requirement for $(a,b)(x,y)=(a,b)$ and $(x,y)(a,b)=(a,b)$, for every $a,b\in S$?

Can you prove associativity?